# Should one minify server code when it's in production?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, node.js

When it comes to the frontend code you always minify it (remove white spaces, comments etc) in production.

Should one do the same with server code? I usually have a lot of comments in my server files. But I have never heard about people doing so.

Wouldn't the server run faster if the code was optimized in the same way?

Comment: You might always minify, but other people might disagree.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're not going to have any improvement as the whitespaces and all formatting are lost when your server side code is translated to machine code (or interpreted). It's also not sent over the wire, it's read from the local filesystem, so while having less characters would lead to a faster startup, it would not make any difference on the long run and the startup speed gain would be marginal (or even unnoticeable).

So, no, minifying your server side code is basically useless, worse, it's probably going to make stack traces completely useless, as there's going to be a lot of code in the same line (and not necessarily with the same formatting you used).

Comment: You can minify the code and keep function names intact, preserving stack trace.

Comment: Minifying does not touch function names, it touches whitespaces and newlines, which would prevent you from finding the real culprit, as there is no new lines to be counted.

Answer (score 18):

I think that minification has more to do with reducing bytes on the wire than it does runtime efficiency.

Comment: Half a nano-second on compile time and never again, am I right?

Comment: I don't know.  Measure it and come back to tell us.

Comment: I would need a compiler level breakdown just before wiring and right after wiring comparison. I'm too busy this week to hack Node.js' source. I'll see next month.

Comment: I'm being sarcastic.  I don't really care.  The question is almost four years old.

Answer (score 6):

i do not believe this offers any benefit to server side code since the server evaluates the code and doesn't actually send it down. If you are looking to optimize production code you can look into setting up a compiler cache such as APC for PHP

Comment: Node.js does not need APC, because node.js does not have share-nothing-architecture like PHP has.

Comment: my answer was referring to server side code like php not js of course javascript would not benefit from php compiler cache

Comment: Okay. But serverside javascript like node.js does also not benefit from APC => bytecode cache...

Comment: You've clearly never hosted a server off a floppy disk...

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of minification is: (1) to minimize the amount of bytes transferred over the network; and (2) to speed up parsing (by the browser).

The equivalent of minification on the server side is byte-code compilation. In Python you have ["Compiled" Python](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/node43.html) (`.pyc` and `.pyo`) files, in PHP you have [Zend Optimizer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/runtime-decoders) and [PHP bytecode Compiler](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bcompiler.php) and in Perl, [B::Bytecode](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/B-C-1.34/lib/B/Bytecode.pm)

On the server size, there's no "transfer over the network", the (source) file is simply read from disk so the performance difference is much smaller in this regard; the main performance gain is from speeding up parsing.